# Why am I obtaining this error when I try to chain 2 map() RxJS operators into a pipe()?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, angular-observable

In an Angular project I have defined these 2 methods:

```
acceptArtistBid(bid: Bid): Observable<Bid[]> {
    console.log("acceptArtistBid() start !!!");

    // define a variable to hold the list of bids
    let listOfBids: Array<Bid>;

    // notice that the Observable is returned by this method and not subscribed in the service
    return this.findArtistBidsAppliedByCurrentWall(bid).pipe(
        // here you use the map of Observable to transform the list, and within this map you call the map Array method to run the transformation on each bid
        map(artistsBisdList => {
            return listOfBids = artistsBisdList.map(bid => {
                bid["test"] = "TEST";
                console.log("CURRENT BID: ", bid);
                return bid;
            })

        }),

        /* Assume updateFirestore$ is a method that returns an Observable representing the update operation.
           This second map operator returns an array of Observables
         */
        map(modiefiedListOfBids => modiefiedListOfBids.map(updatedBid => {
            console.log("UPDATED BID: ", updatedBid);
            // UPDATED updatedBid OBJECT ON FIRESTORE
        }));
        )
}

findArtistBidsAppliedByCurrentWall(bid): Observable<Bid[]> {
    return this.db.collection('bids',
        ref => ref.where("wallId", "==", bid.wallId))
        .snapshotChanges()
        .pipe(
            map(snaps => {
                const courses = this.convertSnaps<Bid>(snaps);
                return courses;
            })
        )
}
```

So, as you can see the `acceptArtistBid()` method first calls the `findArtistBidsAppliedByCurrentWall()` method retrieving an Observable containing an array of `Bid` objects and for this Observable I am defining a `pipe()` chain of RxJS operators. The first operator (that worked fine) simply iterate on each Bid object of this array emitted by the observable and perform a modification of each object (at the moment simply adding a field) building this `listOfBids` containing the array of modified objects.

Then I want to chain a second operator that will iterate on the new Observable represented by the previous `map()` step in the chain in order to print in the console each modified element and the call a method that update it on FireStore database (this second functionality is not yet implemented).

The problem is that when I added these second map in my `pipe()` chain:

```typescript
map(modiefiedListOfBids => modiefiedListOfBids.map(updatedBid => {
    console.log("UPDATED BID: ", updatedBid);

    // UPDATED updatedBid OBJECT ON FIRESTORE
}));
```

the IDE gives me the following error:

```
Type 'Observable<void[]>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Bid[]>'.
  Type 'void[]' is not assignable to type 'Bid[]'.
    Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'Bid'.ts(2322)
```

What is wrong? What am I missing? How can I fix it?

Comment: Now you don't return anything from `modiefiedListOfBids.map`'s callback. Read the information TypeScript is giving you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second `map` returns `void`, you should change it to:

```
map(modiefiedListOfBids => modiefiedListOfBids.map(updatedBid => {
    console.log("UPDATED BID: ", updatedBid);
    return updatedBid;
}));
```

The method expects an `Observable<Bid[]>` and you returned a `Observable<void[]>` (by not returning anything). This is why you get this error.

Comment: rather than doing this, if your only reason for mapping is to log it, it is better to use `tap`

Comment: yes, it is, but I assumed that the final purpose was mapping, so I kept the map in my answer

Comment: @PMO1948 Careful, `Array#map` is not the same thing as `Observable#map`, and there is no such thing as `Array#tap`. Your advice is to replace an instance of `Array#map` with `tap`. That certainly won't work.

Answer (score 1):

You have to return an object of type 'Bid[]' in modiefiedListOfBids.map function.

```
map(modiefiedListOfBids => modiefiedListOfBids.map(updatedBid => {
console.log("UPDATED BID: ", updatedBid);

// UPDATED updatedBid OBJECT ON FIRESTORE

return updatedBid; //return the modified object
}));
```